# Bootstrap 4 - can i have a border showing based on resolution

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to have a border showing on the right for a large resolution but not others.

something like

```
<div class="border-lg-right">blah</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using BS4 the [large breakpoint](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) is 992px

You can do it like

```
// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .border-lg-right {
        border-right: 20px solid red;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Add a css media query like so.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  .border-lg-right {
    border-right: 20px solid red;
  }
}
```

Play around with the calc function if you want to set the border value based on the current screen resolution.

// https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp